# How to achieve double factorial in Python using a function object and a value as parameter

Tags: python

I have just started learning Python and encountered a question which am trying for last 4 hours . I also viewed the another question of this forum for double factorial but that was not of much help .

I want to create a function call doublefact which takes as parameter a function object f and a value v and returns f(f(v)).
For example if f is the factorial function, then doublefact(f, 3) returns (3!)! = 6! = 720.

What I did was closer to this but not getting a proper output and encountered with lots of errors .

```
def factorial(n):
   num = 1
   while n >= 1:
    num = num * n
    n = n - 1
   print(num)

def doublefact(factorial,m):
    temp=factorial(m)
    temp1=factorial(temp)
    print(factorial(temp1))


doublefact(factorial,3)
```

Output :

```
 >>> 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/practice/factorial.py", line 15, in <module>
    doublefact(factorial,3)
  File "C:/Python34/practice/factorial.py", line 11, in doublefact
    temp1=factorial(temp)
  File "C:/Python34/practice/factorial.py", line 4, in factorial
    while n >= 1:
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() >= int()
>>>
```

Comment: Why does your `doublefactorial` function depend on the `factorial` function as a parameter? Why would you ever change it? You probably mean something more generic, like `apply_function_twice(some_function, m)`. This doesn't change what your function does, only what it's called; note also that ['doublefactorial' is actually a specific mathematical function](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial), different from your function.

Comment: As a side-comment not very relevant to the specific question... don't try to make up your rules about indentation; just go with the flow and indent by 4 spaces, never using tab chars... the Python experience will be better. Leave the indentation rules fight to C++, that is not real freedom... just freedom to make confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are not returning any value in your `factorial` function. Instead of `print(num)` use `return num`. The default return value for functions in Python, if there is no `return` statement, is `None` and that's what you are experiencing.

Also, there is an issue with your `doublefact` function in that it computes the factorial three times: as `factorial(m)`, `factorial(temp)` and `factorial(temp1)`.

An example for `3!!`:

```
>>> def factorial(n):
...    num = 1
...    while n >= 1:
...     num = num * n
...     n = n - 1
...    return num
... 
>>> def doublefact(factorial,m):
...     temp=factorial(m)
...     return factorial(temp)
... 
>>> 
>>> doublefact(factorial, 3)
720
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a learning exercise so this answer is not very meaningful.  For future reference Python offers a factorial function within the math module.  For example,

```
In [26]:

import math
print math.factorial(math.factorial(3)) # 720
```

Comment: This should be a comment